# 100% width becomes bigger than bootstrap colum

Tags: html

I want a fixed navigation bar with the width of the middle bootstrap column, but when I set the width to 100% it get's bigger than than this column.
The size of the columns can differ, because they are responsive and the size of the navigation bar has to follow the size of the column.

Here's a picture of the navigation bar

[image]

**CSS**

```
body {
margin:0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

**HTML BODY**

```
<!--bootstrap-->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6" id="middlebackground" >


<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-     color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
<h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
<h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
<h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

<!--bootstrap-->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed elements are relative to viewport, not the parent, so the 100% of width is the 100% of the viewport. To solve, change to absolute and set the parent to relative:

```
#middlebackground { position: relative; }
#middlebackground ul { position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! It does make the bar the right size, but now the bar doesn't stay on the top of my screen when I scroll down...

Comment: Yeah, absolute positioning is relative to parent, not the viewport, it's because fixed elements doesn't scroll and are fixed in the viewport. To achieve what you need, maybe you need to make a calc. If you know the viewport sizes, assuming you have still position fixed, and your <ul> needs to be an 80% of the width of the screen, you can use `ul { width: 80vw; }`

Comment: Ah. okay... I think I will like it better when the bar will be 100% of the viewport and the buttons are centred, so I tried that and it worked. Thanks for helping!!